# How to use a RestTemplate xml file in MockClientHttpRequest/Response

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to stub a response that is coming back from a web server to my application, in order to be able to carry out component tests on my application. 
I have a RestTemplate XML that I would like my requestFactory to consume to create responses based on the XML. Example of the XML is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rates-file xmlns="http://www.example.com/schema/rates-file">
    <timestamp>2017-06-30T14:20:21.768+10:00</timestamp>
    <daily-rates-updated>true</daily-rates-updated>
    <number-of-records>96</number-of-records>
    <rate>
        <transaction-type>transaction</transaction-type>
        <product-code>product</product-code>
        <code>code</code>
        <description>description</description>
        <rate>2.6154</rate>
    </rate>

    <number-of-records>96</number-of-records>
    <rate>
        <transaction-type>transaction2</transaction-type>
        <product-code>product2</product-code>
        <code>code2</code>
        <description>description2</description>
        <rate>2.6154</rate>
    </rate>
  ...
```

For this purpose I am using *MockClientHttpRequest* and *MockClientHttpResponse* (part of spring-test).
How do I have the *MockClientHttpRequest* consume this XML and consequently produce my responses?

**EDIT:** Just to clarify this is the part of code I am trying to direct to my XML:

```
public RatesFile fetchRatesFile() {
...
try {
...
    **ratesFile = restTemplate.postForObject(exampleUrl, variables, RatesFile.class);**
...
}

return ratesFile;
```

}

Instead of overriding *postForObject* method, I would like to write a *RequestFactory* that responds to the *HttpMethod.POST* request by using the XML.

Comment: You want to generate responses that'll vary based on what? The request XML is static. What does your response look like?

Comment: The XML contains bunch of static data. I don't need them to change, I just need them to be sent to the application just like the real server would.

Comment: "I just need them to be sent to the application" - you mean send the response? Or the request?

Show the code you're trying to test. Your question doesn't have sufficient information for me to answer it.

Comment: Here you go I would like to stub the following part of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd not mess with the `RestTemplate`, simply due to the fact that I'd not be testing the Prod code in that case. What I'd do is override `exampleUrl` in my test, and then stand up an endpoint that responds to that. Here's how:

1. If using Spring Boot, simply use the `properties` attribute on `@SpringBootTest` to set  `exampleUrl=http://localhost:8080/test`. Also throw in `@DirtiesContext` in that case. Otherwise, create an `application.properties` in the `src/test/resources` directory and put the property in that.
2. Now either you can create a `@RestController` in the test package that has a method mapped to `/test`, OR
3. Use a mock Web server that you can configure to return canned response. The 2 most popular ones are [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/) and [MockServer](http://www.mock-server.com/)

Using either #2 or #3, you receive the HTTP request and can return whatever response you want to based on that.

Comment: I have not used your solution yet, but talking to some people it seems like a good option. If anyone else has adopted the solution please provide more details. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SSF I'm not sure what you mean by "If anyone else has adopted the solution". We use this technique all the time in our code, and AFAIK, so does the Spring team. It's no rocket science - you don't want to change code for testing it, so you mock the external dependency.