# How to Mock HttpResponse for the Web Service (Using JavaHttpClient)?

Tags: java, json, junit, mockito, httpresponse

I have WebService Call using Java Http Client. Need to do Junit testing using Mockito for the Response of WebService (HttpResponse).

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
HttpResponse httpResponse= JavaHttpClient.callWebService("URL",object);
String json = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
response = gson.fromJson(json, ClassName.class);
log.info("Response: " + new Gson().toJson(response));
```

How to set the mock values for httpResponse.getEntity() ? and this should be convert to JSON as above

Thanks
Nithyanandan K

Comment: Is `JavaHttpClient` static? If so, it would not be possible in mockito, but be possible in PowerMock.

Comment: that i have changed by creating interface. I Need like how to mock the response.getentity() values.

Comment: You can then mock the interface, create an HttpResponse, and fill it with dummy data, and then return that through the interface mock.

Comment: I have mocked the interface, But facing issue in mocking the dummy values to HttpResponse.

Comment: Will you please help me out. how to set dummy values to HttpResponse. Especially GetEntity.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44941408/839733

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample MockServer. Modify it for your requirement.

```
import static org.mockserver.integration.ClientAndServer.startClientAndServer;
import static org.mockserver.model.HttpRequest.request;
import static org.mockserver.model.HttpResponse.response;

import org.mockserver.client.server.MockServerClient;
import org.mockserver.initialize.ExpectationInitializer;
import org.mockserver.model.Header;
import org.mockserver.model.HttpStatusCode;

public class MockServerInitializer implements ExpectationInitializer {

  /**
   * Standalone mock server
   *
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MockServerClient mockServerClient = startClientAndServer(9999);
    defineMockServerBehaviour(mockServerClient);
  }

  @Override
  public void initializeExpectations(MockServerClient mockServerClient) {
    defineMockServerBehaviour(mockServerClient);
  }

  public static void defineMockServerBehaviour(MockServerClient mockServer) {

    mockServer.when(
      request()
        .withMethod("POST")
        .withPath("/Sample")
    ).respond(
      response()
        .withStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK_200.code())
        .withHeader(Header.header("Content-Type", "application/xml"))
        .withBody("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n" +
          "<Response>\n" +
          "    <responseStatus>OK</responseStatus>\n" +
          "</Response>"));
  }
}
```